# How do I prevent `<br>` from parsing inside my `[code]` tags?

Tags: php, syntaxhighlighter

I am having some trouble (again :P) with my BB-code system. I finally got `[code]` tags working using [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). Now there is one problem, that when "enter" is pressed inside the script (AKA next line), the bb-code causes that enter to be replaced with `<br>` which means the script does not correctly render the code using Syntax Highlighter.

Example picture:

[image: Example picture]

How do I create an exception in my code, that ignores the `<br>` when it is inside `[code]` lines?

My current bbcode.php (there are more things in those arrays, but they are not relevant):

```
function bbcode($input) {
  $find = array( 
    "@\n@", 
    "/\[code\=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/code\]/is"
  );
  $replace = array( 
    "<br />",
    "<pre class='brush: $1;'>$2</pre>"
  );
  $input = htmlspecialchars($input);
  $input= preg_replace($find, $replace, $input);
  return $input;
}
```

To sum it up: How do I prevent `<br>` from parsing inside my `[code]` tags?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Does nobody know this? I honestly can't find a solution :(