# What is a (free) rich text editor that allows for code syntax highlighting (code snippets)?

Tags: javascript, code-snippets, rich-text-editor

I am looking for a rich text editor that allows for code highlighting. I have worked on a BB-code system myself, and seeing as [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583075/how-do-i-prevent-br-from-parsing-inside-my-code-tags) turned out without any replies, I have not found a way (after countless of hours of searching) how to solve this. Therefore, I am bound to use an existing rich text editor, but it is important that it has the ability to add code snippets.

I am looking for a JavaScript or jQuery based one, since my server does not run ASP (or many other languages unfortunately).

Before I will get the reply "sigh repost", I have spend hours of searching and on topics regarding rich text editors, there were not any suggestions that have the ability to add code snippets, or they are using ASP. Therefore, my question is **not** a repost, so please don't bother commenting these replies!

If there are not any available, is there any way I can easily implement for example [Alex Gorbatchev's Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) into a simple rich text editor? Or perhaps any other? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Basically, I am looking for a way to do something similar as the rich text box used on Stack Overflow (with code snippet syntaxing).

Thanks!

PS. If it is unclear what I am questioning, please refer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583075/how-do-i-prevent-br-from-parsing-inside-my-code-tags), that might make things more clear.

Comment: Notepad++ is good enough for me.

Comment: Have a look at [ACE from cloud9](http://ace.c9.io/) and [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/). SO uses *MarkDown*, one option would be [EpicEditor MarkDown](http://epiceditor.com/). Your question would be probably better suited at [SE Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Scooby - You don't understand the question, but yes, I think everyone uses Notepad++ in the end :P

Comment: @pasty - Thanks, Ill check those out!